# linker on Visual studio with a header

Tags: visual-studio, linker

I use a code that I found on the net. I have a header called pdflow_cudalib.h which must be a linker (.lib or .dll ?), but I don't know how a header can become a linker.

is there a simple solution to resolve my probleme with visual studio ?

Answer (score 0):

A header and a library (.dll or .lib) are different things. You would need both. the header (.h) is not a library which you can link to your program. You use the header to interface with the library and in addition, you need to link to it via its .dll or .lib.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but in the CmakeLists.txt the pdflow_cudalib.h is considerd like a linker :
 
 ADD_EXECUTABLE(Scene-Flow-Visualization  
  main_scene_flow_visualization.cpp
  scene_flow_visualization.cpp
  scene_flow_visualization.h
  legend_pdflow.xpm)
  
 TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Scene-Flow-Visualization
   ${MRPT_LIBS}
   ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenNI_lib}
   pdflow_cudalib)

Comment: Can you publish a link to this document? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Looks like this part is the .lib file
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Scene-Flow-Visualization ${MRPT_LIBS} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${OpenNI_lib}

Comment: yes, https://github.com/MarianoJT88/PD-Flow
I am working on this project (and more precisely on real-time scene flow with visualization)

Comment: So if you are using Windows, the section is
 IF (WIN32)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{OPENNI2_INCLUDE})
  LINK_DIRECTORIES($ENV{OPENNI2_LIB})
  SET(OpenNI_lib "$ENV{OPENNI2_LIB}/OpenNI2.lib"

Comment: yes, and I have also : TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Scene-Flow-Visualization
   ${MRPT_LIBS}
   ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenNI_lib}
   pdflow_cudalib)